# Why does android studio does not recognize the "package net.simplifiedcoding.spacefighter;" code?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Firstof all i am new to android game programming.This is the GameView java class. I did not write the code and to find the other files you can visit https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-game-development-tutorial-1/    . When i compile everything, android studio gives me error. why is that?

```
 package net.simplifiedcoding.spacefighter;

 import android.graphics.Paint;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.graphics.Canvas;
 import android.graphics.Color;
 import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
 import android.view.SurfaceView;

 public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

volatile boolean playing;
private Thread gameThread = null;

//adding the player to this class
private net.simplifiedcoding.spacefighter.Player player;

//These objects will be used for drawing
private Paint paint;
private Canvas canvas;
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    //initializing player object
    player = new net.simplifiedcoding.spacefighter.Player(context);

    //initializing drawing objects
    surfaceHolder = getHolder();
    paint = new Paint();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (playing) {
        update();
        draw();
        control();
    }
}

private void update() {
    //updating player position
    player.update();
}

private void draw() {
    //checking if surface is valid
    if (surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
        //locking the canvas
        canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        //drawing a background color for canvas
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        //Drawing the player
        canvas.drawBitmap(
                player.getBitmap(),
                player.getX(),
                player.getY(),
                paint);
        //Unlocking the canvas
        surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
    }
}

private void control() {
    try {
        gameThread.sleep(17);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void pause() {
    playing = false;
    try {
        gameThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}

public void resume() {
    playing = true;
    gameThread = new Thread(this);
    gameThread.start();
}
```

}

Comment: the thing is the link you gave me and the problem i encountered are different. I am asking why package net. ... not working because when i followed the tutorial from the website called simplified coding, then i think the code i posted wanted to import classes from files in the website.

Comment: It's the same issue. In java your folder structure has to match the your package names. That's your problem and that's the problem described in the duplicate.

Comment: Got it. I realized i have to change the name of the folder under java file in android studio to net.simplifiedcode.sacefiter. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No worries, happy coding